# Vagrant machine events

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-plugin

I'm trying to understand if there is the possibility to develop a vagrant plugin that permits through the vagrantfile to attach custom beahviours to vm events, such the execution of shell commands.

For example a *vagrant rsync* after a command like *composer install* has been run on the virtual machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: _such the execution of shell commands_ I am not sure what you're looking but isn't [shell provisioning](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html) execute shell commands on the vm ?

Comment: Could you clarify your question - Are you trying to trigger actions on the HOST after an event on the GUEST?

Comment: The short story is I would like to run a command on the host after I run a command on the guest.

Comment: The long story is that vb shared folders suck when using large folders. I've tried everything but no luck so I'm thinking to leave the composer vendor folder outside the shared folder and rsync them back on the host when they change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [vagrant-triggers](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers)

plugin